# How do I get Ubuntu Software Center to stop trying to download a package on startup?

Tags: software-center, flash

I downloaded some things (Wine was in there) to try and get Flash working (or Flash working for DRM stuff) based on directions I read on a website. It seemed to work (at least I can watch video from Acorn.TV now), but now whenever I startup Ubuntu Software Center (or, strangely, Komodo IDE) I get a popup dialog that says:

> Please wait, downloading...
>
> Downloading wine-shockwave-installer (12 MiB)

eventually it either finishes or gives up and then the software proceeds normally.

How would I get that to stop occurring?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an awful solution, I used Synaptic Package Manager, tiped "wine" in the Quick filter, and reinstalled all my wine packages, after that the dialog stopped. 
WARNING: I am very noob with ubuntu, dont blame me if something breakes or stops working, it just worked for me.